# Select2 multiselect dropdown ng-keypress not working [AngularJS]

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

I'm going to load the drop-down content on keypress, without loading everything onload. But here my loadcourses() function is not getting fired.

Html:

```
<select id="mySelect" class="form-control select2 comboBox" multiple="multiple" ng-model="courses" ng-keypress="loadcourses()">
  <option ng-repeat="value in coursesList" value={{value.Name}}>
        {{value.Name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

AngulaJS code:

```
$scope.loadcourses = function () {
    console.log('loading from remote server');
}
```

Comment: This function fired only when you click drop down then press any key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.loadcourses = function() {
    $scope.coursesList = [{
        id: '1',
        name: 'Option A'
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Option B'
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        name: 'Option C'
      }
    ]
    console.log('loading from remote server');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body >
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div tabindex="0" ng-keypress="loadcourses()">
      <select id="mySelect" class="form-control select2 comboBox" multiple="multiple" ng-model="courses">
  <option ng-repeat="value in coursesList" value={{value.name}}>
        {{value.name}}
  </option>
</select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-init` instead of `ng-keypress`, so DOM will load coursesList array on `<select>` tag only

```
<select id="mySelect" class="form-control select2 comboBox" multiple="multiple" ng-model="courses" ng-init="loadcourses()">
  <option ng-repeat="value in coursesList" value={{value.Name}}>
        {{value.Name}}
  </option>
</select>
```